# load a set of pictures in memory with opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I'm renewing an old code in C with C API OpenCV and I need to load at least 300 images in memory to make some algorithms with them.

So, I've been thinking that I can load that images in memory to make operations more faster instead to load from disk and make a single operation each one.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with C code, then your images will automatically stay in memory until you explicitly release them. Simply call `cvLoadImage` on each image you wish to load from disk. I would recommend you store the `IplImage*` pointers in a big array so you don't lose track of them. When you're done, simply call `cvReleaseImage` and the memory will all be freed.

As you mentioned, you'll have to watch out as you're loading that you don't run out of memory. If you do, you'll have no option but to only load a subset into memory and keep the rest on disk.

Comment: Thank you aardvark. I've done a big array of IplImage* and load all the images on memory. This  works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the performance gain from doing this would be so little for most applications that it isn't even worth the trouble. The only way to be sure that there would be any gain, is by doing it and measuring the time.

The problem with your approach is that depending on the size of the images, you might run out of RAM memory to store them all at once.

Comment: Uhhh... Performance gain from preloading data to memory from disk not worth the trouble? Can you please explain?

Comment: I would love to see some research that states that this practice is ALWAYS worth the trouble. The fact is that this may not be true for every single application. edsonlp1 will have to test and measure his gains before he settles for an approach.

Comment: I think it depends entirely on whether the operations can be done serially on the images or not. If the operations can't be done serially (i.e. do all operations on one image, then move to the next), then there will be huge gains from keeping the images in memory. Otherwise, there's no point, because you'll still have to load them and save them back to disk. There may be mild gains from loading in one thread while processing in another, but they would likely be small...

Comment: Disk access is expensive, memory access is expensive too, but much cheaper. If you know you will reuse some data (not just process and forget) it's better to cache in memory. I'm not saying that keeping stuff in memory is always a good idea, but I strongly disagree with your statement, that "the performance gain from doing this would be so little for most applications that it isn't even worth the trouble" given you don't know what actually the application does.

Comment: See what we are doing here? Speculating. There is a lot of important info that is not in the question. All I said in my answer is: heads up, there is no way to know unless you try it (due to the lack of information provided in the question).

Comment: @zrxq: Do you know anything about the algorithms? What if the algorithm takes a second to run on an image on average. Is it worth having the overhead for a few ms gain? As long as we don't know what's done to the images, everything is speculation.